# Is it possible in Swift to require an associated type to conform to an associated protocol of an associated type?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

I am attempting (for essentially no reason) to make a protocol which describes categories from category theory. I have tried to come up with something like this.

```swift
protocol Category {
    associatedtype Object: Protocol
}
protocol Hom {
    associatedtype C: Category
    associatedtype Source: C.Object
    associatedtype Target: C.Object
}
```

In particular, I want each Hom type to have an associated category C and an associated Source and Target type which are both objects in that category. Consequently, I have associated an Object protocol to each Category, and have tried to make the Source and Target of a Hom conform to the Object protocol for the corresponding Category. The code above fails to compile with

```
Type 'Self.Source' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'Self.C.Object'
```

This error is at least unclear, for C.Object is declared as a protocol. Is there any way I can work around this issue?

**Edit:**

As Rob has pointed out, the code as is does not make much sense. Protocol is a particular class from ObjC and is not a type which describes protocols. Further, there is no type that describes all protocols, because protocols themselves cannot conform to protocols as they are just requirements on other types. What I was looking for is a metatype which Any.Protocol, Sequence.Protocol, etc. were all instances of.

I will go into more detail as to what kind of construction I am trying to describe.

A category is a type Object and a type of homomorphisms between every pair of instances of Object. For two instances of Object, A and B, the type of homomorphisms is generally written as Hom(A,B), but I will write `Hom<A,B>` to be Swiftier. Categories then come equipped with composition which has the signature `<A: Object, B: Object, C: Object>(_ f: Hom<A,B>, _ g: Hom<B,C>) -> Hom<A,C>`.

If f is an instance of `Hom<A,B>`, then A is called the source or domain of f and B is called the target or codomain of f.

Types themselves are then a category where Object is the metatype of all types and `Hom<A,B> = (A) -> B`.

The primary reason categories are difficult in Swift is because Swift does not have dependent types. There is no way to describe a category whose object type is Int because there is no way to have a type `Hom<0,0>`. However, if the Object type is required to be a metatype, then suddenly `Hom<A,B>` is a sensical thing to describe to the type system because an instance of a metatype is a type (I think), which can be a generic parameter. This is what I attempted to describe by setting Object: Protocol.

In Swift, I would really wish to describe

```swift
protocol Category {
    associatedtype Object: Metatype
    associatedtype Hom<A: Object, B: Object>
    func compose<A: Object, B: Object, C: Object>(_ f: Hom<A,B>, then g: Hom<B,C>) -> Hom<A,C>
}
```

but this is also a non-starter because associated types cannot have generic parameters.

In my use case, I have a protocol that describes finitely generated abelian groups and a protocol that describes finitely generated unital rings, and I would love to write generic code which does not care whether or not it is working with `GroupHom<A,B> where A: AbelianGroup, B: Abelian Group`,  `RingHom<A,B> where A: Ring, B: Ring`, or `(A) -> B` as each of these come equipped with the correct kind of composition.

It might just be impossible to do this, which I would be willing to accept. Please let me know if this is different enough that it should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: `associatedtype Object: Protocol` is almost certainly not doing what you think it's doing. `Protocol` is not a type in Swift, and in this context it doesn't mean "a Swift protocol." It's an ObjC class you're importing from the ObjC runtime (likely via Foundation) that holds metadata about an ObjC protocol. The Swift equivalent would be `Any.Protocol`, but that's not itself a protocol or class, so you can't constrain Object to it.

Comment: (And `Any.Protocol` doesn't even really capture what you're trying to say, because other protocols are not subtypes of `Any.Protocol`)

Answer (score 3):

```
associatedtype Object: Protocol
```

This line doesn't mean what you think it means. `Protocol` isn't part of Swift. It's part of the ObjC runtime. (It's a really confusing import.)

But even if it did mean that, I don't believe it would help you. It is important to realize that in Swift, protocols do not conform to protocols, and protocols with associated types are not types. They're constraints on types. This tends to creep in all over the place and surprise people.

My suspicion is that you're looking to model things along these lines (note that my category theory is very weak, so please forgive me if I use the wrong terms at points).

We want to get to a point where we can say "a category has a collection of objects and a collection of arrows between those objects." To get there, I think we'd want to start with a generic Arrow:

```
protocol Arrow {
    associatedtype Source
    associatedtype Target
    var apply: (Source) -> Target { get }
}
```

A homomorphism is an arrow that maps back to its own type.

```
protocol Homomorphism: Arrow where Source == Target {
    typealias Object = Source
}
```

And with that, we can express a Category:

```
protocol Category {
    associatedtype Object
    associatedtype Arrow: Homomorphism where Arrow.Object == Object
}
```

I'd like to talk about the category of integers and functions (I believe that's a proper category). So first I need functions.

```
struct Function<Source, Target>: Arrow {
    let apply: (Source) -> Target
}

extension Function: Homomorphism where Source == Target {}
```

And then I can declare the category.

```
struct Integers: Category {
    typealias Object = Int
    typealias Arrow = Function<Int, Int>
}
```

And create a morphism.

```
let increment = Function(apply: { (x: Int) in x + 1 })
```

I think this is somewhat the direction you're looking for.

Comment: This is close to what I’m looking for. In particular, your explanation of what Protocol means and how protocols do not conform to protocols is very useful. 

Homomorphisms are not required to have the same source and target. An endomorphism is a homomorphism with identical source and target, and so you have helped me implement endomorphisms, which are some of the most important homomorphisms anyway. You have described is the endomorphisms of Int in the category of Types. 

I have edited my question to be clearer about the kind of structure I want to describe. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

dg

In swift you cannot use a protocol associatedtype as an associatedType cause it is not defined what type is.

Associated Type can only be used as a constraint for types, like this:

```
protocol Category {
    associatedtype Object1:Equatable
}

class Homs:Category{
    typealias Object1 = Int

    func sum(element:Object1){

        print(element+element)
    }
}
```

Or like this

```
protocol Category {
    associatedtype Object1: Equatable
}

protocol Homs {
    associatedtype Cat:Category
    associatedtype Source: Category where Source.Object1 == Cat.Object1
    associatedtype Target: Category where Target.Object1 == Cat.Object1
}
```

The reason of why your code not compile, is cause, your associatedtype Target is constrained to implements a associatedType (that is not defined) of a protocol. Someone need to define it before to use as a constraint.

An approach to resolve your problem clould be, generate a generic class. Let's to see it:

```
protocol Category {
    associatedtype Object1: Equatable
}

class Homs<Cat:Category,Source,Target> where Cat.Object1 == Source && Cat.Object1 == Target.Object1{

}
```

Another approach could be create a generic Category class, and a protocol with type for Category class, category Class, Source and Target conforming to Type:

```
class Category<T>{
}

protocol Homs {
    associatedtype ObjectType
    associatedtype Cat:Category<ObjectType>
    associatedtype Source where Source == ObjectType
    associatedtype Target where Target == ObjectType
}
```

O something like the second example:

```
protocol Category {
    associatedtype Object1: Equatable
}

protocol Homs {
    associatedtype Cat:Category
    associatedtype Source: Category where Source.Object1 == Cat.Object1
    associatedtype Target: Category where Target.Object1 == Cat.Object1
}
```

Remember, You cannot use protocols with associated types as a type constraint for associated type or as a type for a variable or constant, first someone need to define the associated types.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: This is informative, but not quite what I am looking for. I have edited the question for clarity. I am not looking for the Source and Target to be equal to the type Object from the category. Instead, I want Source and Target to be subtypes of the metatype Object. I am not sure that is even possible.

Comment: If your propose is call the same "function" with different types, (in this case composition function), only you need to make a base protocol with all functions, make other protocols (Abelian group and Ring) implements these protocols in a related class or extending Types like Int, Double, or whatever you want. For the final use, for example, you can create a variable like this -> `var baseClass:BaseProtocol?` set it for example with a class that implements BaseProtocol, for example an Int extended from BaseProtocol: `var baseClass;BaseProtocol? = Int()` and `baseClass.compose(a:5,b:3)`

Comment: @deaton.dg then you need to cast the result like this: `var result:Category<Int,Int> = baseClass.compose(a:5,b:3) as! Category<Int,Int> `.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your meaning. Are you suggesting that I provide a type-erased composition and rely on optional unwrapping when I know that the composition is well defined? That would certainly work, but I would rather have compile-time safety in that regard. For clarity, I have linked a simplified code sample of precisely the polymorphism I wish to describe with these protocols. https://pastebin.com/x4kg95Qs